# Using Knex .withRecursive

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I cannot figure how to make this query work in using Knex.
The query is working fine in my SQL client.

Using postgis:latest image / latest Knex version

```
WITH RECURSIVE childs AS (
    SELECT id, ARRAY[id] as path, false as cycle FROM taxonomy WHERE taxonomy.id = 4
UNION
    SELECT T.id, path || T.id, T.id = ANY(path) FROM taxonomy T INNER JOIN childs C ON C.id = T.parent_id AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT id FROM childs
```

I tried

```
client
    .withRecursive(
      'childs',
      knex.raw(
        `SELECT id, ARRAY[id] as path, false as cycle FROM taxonomy WHERE taxonomy.id = ?
       UNION
       SELECT T.id, path || T.id, T.id = ANY(path) FROM taxonomy T INNER JOIN childs C ON C.id = T.parent_id AND NOT cycle`,
        [4]
      )
    )
    .select('id')
    .from('childs')
```

But it gives me this error : **SELECT * with no tables specified is not valid**

Any ideas ?

Comment: The function definition of `withRecursice` ist different. The second argument is the knex/db object as callback parameter.  https://knexjs.org/#Builder-withRecursive

Comment: I did not changed anything, beside restarting my image and now it's working ... 
Wish i knew why.
 
( The spec does say we can use .raw() ( "callback|builder|raw" ) ) 
Not sure what to make of this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using knex functions other than raw works as well:

```js
knex
  .withRecursive('ancestors', (qb) => {
    qb.select('*')
      .from('people')
      .where('people.id', 1)
      .union((qb) => {
        qb.select('*')
          .from('people')
          .join(
            'ancestors', 
            'ancestors.parentId', 
            'people.id'
          )
      })
  })
  .select('*')
  .from('ancestors')
```